# MongoDb - How to find documents where position of element1 in array is less than position of element2?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So if I have a basic mongo doc with an array such as:

```
{
  myId: 1
  nodes: [
   {nodeId: 1},
   {nodeId: 2},
   {nodeId: 3}
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  myId: 1
  nodes: [
   {nodeId: 2},
   {nodeId: 3},
   {nodeId: 1}
  ]
}
```

I want to have a query to find all documents where the position of **nodeId: 2** in the array is less than **nodeId: 1**. So for the example above I only want to pull back the second document since **nodeId: 2** appears before **nodeId: 1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$indexofArray` in combination with `$redact`.

`$lt` to compare indexes and `$$KEEP` when document when condition is met else `$$PRUNE` to remove the document.

Something like

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
  "$redact": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$lt": [
          {
            "$indexOfArray": [
              "$nodes.nodeId",
              2
            ]
          },
          {
            "$indexOfArray": [
              "$nodes.nodeId",
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "$$KEEP",
      "$$PRUNE"
    ]
  }
})
```

Mongo DB Java Driver Code:

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db_name");
 MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = database.getCollection("collection_name");
 Document query = Document.parse("{\n" +
                "  \"$redact\": {\n" +
                "    \"$cond\": [\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"$lt\": [\n" +
                "          {\n" +
                "            \"$indexOfArray\": [\n" +
                "              \"$nodes.nodeId\",\n" +
                "              2\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "          },\n" +
                "          {\n" +
                "            \"$indexOfArray\": [\n" +
                "              \"$nodes.nodeId\",\n" +
                "              1\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "          }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"$$KEEP\",\n" +
                "      \"$$PRUNE\"\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}");
 List<Document> documents  = mongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(query)).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to do this with projections and filters?

Comment: Np. Are you referring to mongo java driver implementation ?

Comment: Yeap I am. Having trouble getting this translated to java